# 2-thread Perl program slower if run using a RAMdisk within a Virtualbox?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, performance, perl, ramdisk

I run a perl script inside a Virtualbox (both the host and guest OS are Windows 7). 
The Virtualbox has been given 4 CPUs out of 8 (everything runs on a Intel i7) and 3 GB RAM (out of 8 available).

The 2-threaded perl program, which has plenty of RAM available, does a lot of I/O, reading and writing files and issueing perl "system" commands (i.e. executes external programs).

To achieve better performance, I tried using a RAM disk (512 MB, enough to contain both input and output files).

I copied there all input files and the script (slightly modified in order to consider the new disk). **The output files are created correctly on the RAM disk, but surprisingly, it takes much more time than using the ordinary hard disk.**

Here are the "benchmarks":

with    RAM disk:  about 1 H 03 min 45 sec.

without RAM disk: about      32 min 15 sec.

(please remember, everything runs inside a Virtualbox and the RAM disk is configured *inside* the guest OS).

Only the perl.exe and libraries still remain on the 'ordinary' C: disk.

What happens?
Why the RAM disk hasn't improved the benchmark?